# Google Analytics and Play show different number of installations

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I've connected my application to Google Analytics but it shows different data than Google Play. For example at 26th November Google Play shows 262 new installations but in Google Analytics for that day I have 1012 new users. Why there is such a big difference?

Answer (score 0):

There are more bots running to spam Google Analytics report like you may get unexpected lot of user from any country or like if you developed your app for android. In your analytics report you may see the platforms mac, linux etc., but you actually developed your app only for Android or IOS

> So Be aware of Spammers

Take a look at this [article](https://www.optimizesmart.com/geek-guide-removing-referrer-spam-google-analytics/) it may help you how to see your original reports on your tracking ID